# Questions about Web workers in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using web workers in the background page of my extension. I noticed a few things and wanted to clarify:

1. What is the limit on number of workers that can be spawned? I see that my extension starts crashing somewhere around 125 workers.
2. I spawn 100 workers. They do some work and call "self.close()" after they are finished. However, I think there memory is not reclaimed. If I don't spawn any workers, the extension uses around 54MB. If I spawn 100 workers, the extension keeps on using about 107MB even after all of them have terminated. Is there any way to release that memory?